# ASP.NET Cache Management

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have three applications running in three separate app pools. One of the applications is an administrative app that few people have privileged access to. One of the function the administrative app allows is creating downtime notices. So when a user goes into the administrative app and creates a downtime notice the other two apps are supposed to pick up on there being a new notice and display it on the login page.

The problem is that these notices are cached and being that each app is in a separate app pool the administrative app doesn't have any way to clear the downtime notices cache in the other two applications.

I'm trying to figure out a way around this. The only thing I can think of is to insert a record in the DB that denotes the cache needs to be cleared and the other two apps will check the DB when loading the login page. Does anyone have another approach that might work a little cleaner?

*Side note, this is more widespread than just the downtime notices, but I just used this as an example.

**EDIT**

Restarting the app pools is not feasible as it will most likely kill background threads.

Comment: Is restarting the app pools for the two applications from the administrative app a solution for you?

Comment: You mention clearing cache, but it's not clear how the downtime notice gets into the cache of the other two apps in the first place? How do the other two apps "pick up on there being a new notice?"

Comment: Zaid, they make a call to the cache which if it's not already populated gets the data from the DB and stores it in the cache, otherwise it returns what the cache has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're basically trying to send a message from the administrative app to other apps. Maybe you should consider creating WCF service on these apps that could be called from the administrative application. That is a standard way to communicate between different apps if you don't want to use e.g. shared medium such a database and it doesn't force you to use polling model.

Comment: I started going down this route, but since each app is a separate domain (http//www.a.com, http//www.b.com, http//www.c.com) do I need to handle cross domain web services or can I do it without going out to the web?

Comment: If the apps are hosted on the same IIS you may always limit communication to localhost without exposing services to the internet. You may also use another binding, e.g. NetNamedPipeBinding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at this is that this is basically an inter-application messaging problem, which has a number of libraries already out there that could help you solve it.  [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) comes to mind for this.  It has a C# client all ready to go.  [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is another potential technology, and one that already comes with Windows - you just need to install it.

Comment: MSMQ would also work and it is already part of Windows (optional install). You just need to install it.

Comment: @Kevin That it would!  A good call.  I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's database information you're caching, you might try your luck at setting up and [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx).

Otherwise, I would recommend not using the ASP.NET cache, and either find a 3rd party solution that uses a distributed caching scheme, that way all applications are using one cache, instead of 3 separate ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is the best answer or even the right answer, its just what I did.

I have a series of ecommerce websites on separate servers and data centers that rely on pulling catalog data from a central backoffice website location and then caches them locally. In my first iteration of this I simply used GET requests that the central location could ping the corresponding consuming website to initiate its own cache refresh routine. I used SSL on each of the eCommerce servers as I already had that setup and could then have the backoffice web app send credentials via SSL GET to initiate the refresh securely.

At a later stage, we found it more efficient to use sockets instead on the backoffice where each consuming website would be a client and listen for changes in the data. The backoffice website could then communicate to its corresponding website when a particular account change and then communicate this very specifically. This approach is much more granular and we could update in small bits as needed as opposed to a large chunked update but this was definitely more complicated than our first try.